# Select box CSS formatting

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

My form is from the ruby on rails tutorial by Michael Hartl, but I added in a `collection_select` and it looks kind of goofy:

[image]

The CSS to generate input boxes is

```
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Which is also the only instance of select popping up in my CSS. I tried adding select to the second input block, but that didn't change anything. The code for these 3 boxes are

```
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :unit %>
<%= f.collection_select :unit, @units, :id, :name, prompt: true %>

<%= f.label :phone %>
<%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>
```

and the HTML produced by my form is

```
<input class="form-control" type="email" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
<select name="user[unit]" id="user_unit">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="2">...</option>
  <option value="3">...</option>
</select>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="user[phone]" id="user_phone">
```

What can I do to make the select the same look as the text boxes?

Comment: Add padding to your `<select>`.

Comment: `select:not([multiple]) {  
    padding: 6px;  
}`

Answer (score 2):

Change CSS as follows,

```
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Adding padding is the best way to control the height of form elements.

Comment: Two quesations: 1) What about the rounded edges? Would I have to mess with a radius setting? 2) Do you have any idea why despite being within the `form_for` block, the collection select doesn't highlight red like the rest of the `form-control` validations? Maybe because the form is for user but the collection select is for units?

Comment: 1) Adding padding will not affect rounded corners. You should be having rounded corners as in the image you included in the question itself.

Comment: 2) The red box you see around elements is HTML validation. There's no need of validating a drop down in HTML level since all the <option>s are considered as valid responses.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the [height of the `select`](https://jsfiddle.net/m74hko8a/3/):

```
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input,select {
  height: 25px;
}

input:hover,
input:focus,
select:hover,
select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```